# How to display HTML using Python Alone in localhost

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am trying to display my html files using python alone. Such as I would `python code.py` and I would be able to access my html at `localhost:8080`

html files are static files that access each other. For example, `index.html` directs to `contact.html` and all of them access `css` folder.

How do I open my html files so it displays it on the webpage?

below is what I have so far.

```
html_file = []
with open("index.html", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        html_file.append(line)
```

Is there way to do `python code.py` and when I access `localhost:8000` that would show me the code? and I can access each page.

here is an example html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img class="resize" src="./pictures/logo.png" alt="logo">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class="active"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
                    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
                })
            </script>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's way to do so using the python web frameworks like `Flask` or `Django`. In a typical flask scenario your code would look like this:-

1) Install flask:-

```
pip install flask
```

2) Write your `code.py` like this:-

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('hello.html')
```

3) Next create a templates `folder` inside which put your html file which I have named it to be `hello.html`

```
templates > hello.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img class="resize" src="./pictures/logo.png" alt="logo">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class="active"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
                    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
                })
            </script>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

4) Your directory structure would look like this:-

```
/code.py
/templates
    /hello.html
```

5) Run `python code.py` and you can see your page on `localhost:5000`.