# How to display HTML using LXML in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, lxml

So what I am trying to achieve is really simple.

I want to call `python test.py` and would like to go to my local host and see the html result. However I keep getting an error `ValueError: Invalid tag name u'<html><body><h1>Test!</h1></body></html>'`

Below is my code. What's the problem here?

```
import lxml.etree as ETO
html = ETO.Element("<html><body><h1>Test!</h1></body></html>")
self.wfile.write(ETO.tostring(html, xml_declaration=False, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: Are you trying to read an existing file or create a new one?

Comment: @JackFleeting I am trying to read existing file!

Comment: lxml is not a web server. This looks similar to another question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61683853/407651

Answer (score 0):

You have to create each element in turn, and put them in the structure that you want them to have:

```
html = ETO.Element('html')
body = ETO.SubElement(html, 'body')
h1 = ETO.SubElement(body, 'h1')
h1.text = 'Test!'
```

Then ETO.tostring(html) will return a bytestring that looks like this:

```
>>> ETO.tostring(html)
b'<html><body><h1>Test!</h1></body></html>'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've dont it before but I realize it's just too much for big files. I want to read the html file within python without creating each element in turn. How do I do that?

Comment: If you already have an HTML file, why are you recreating it? I guess I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The python file itself has other functionalities that would be faster in production time if I can just start the server and show my html file in the python code itself. I was wondering if there is any way how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading an existing file, `Element` isn't useful here; try changing this

```
html = ETO.Element("<html><body><h1>Test!</h1></body></html>")
```

to this

```
html = ETO.fromstring("<html><body><h1>Test!</h1></body></html>")
```

and see if it works for you.